# Limit of a convergent sequence of integers

Tags: limits, numerical-methods

Let $(a_n)_{n∈\mathbb N^+}$ be a sequence of integers which converges to a limit $\lambda$. Show that $\exists N \in \mathbb N^+$ such that
$a_n = \lambda\ \forall\,n > N$.

Comment: Choose $\epsilon < 1$ and follow your definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Show that there is $N \in \Bbb N $ such that $|a_n-a_m|<1$ for $n,m > N$

fred